# Find out which line will be executed in Visual Studio debug mode

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, breakpoints

How can I find out which line will be executed after performing any action?

If I know what will be executed I can put break point there. But what if I am not sure where to set breakpoint or just I need to go to the executing line faster (without setting breakpoints).

"Break All" is not what I look for. It is pausing debugging, so I cannot perform any action (just after which I want Visual Studio sets breakpoint automatically)

In other words, for example I want to start debugging each line after clicking a button, without putting breakpoints. Is it possibile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a .NET application you can use my [Runtime Flow](https://vlasovstudio.com/runtime-flow/) tool (30-day trial) to see code that is executed after some action.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know if i will be using it, but more or less this I meant.

Comment: When i click run, i get a windows with the message "Output file name required for the Start Project option.", what does that mean?

Comment: @StackTrace It usually means that this project type is not recognized by Runtime Flow and you need to use Customized Run instead of Run.

Answer (score 0):

Set a breakpoint at the line you want to stop after. Then once the breakpoint is hit **Step Into** or press `F11` in Visual Studio. This takes you to the very next line of code that executes, no matter where it is in the project.

Comment: In 99% of cases I do it. But if I don't know where to set breakpoint?

Comment: If you're trying to find out where the class/method that's being called is then you can right click on the class/method and press `Go To Definition` or put your cursor in the middle of the method name and press `F12` without having to be in debug mode.

Comment: I know it too :) But this time I need that Visual Studio will show me, what will be executed after some action.  (clicking button is not the best example, because I know what it will be, but in 1% of cases, I don't know)

Comment: @tauri - could you define "some action"? Obviously, different code will be executed after different actions.

Comment: Some actions I mean clicking Button, editing or deleting text in TextBox, closing window ect.