# Is there a way to locate a code block from a GUI in debug mode?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, user-interface

I'm digging through a program that contains a lot of forms with names that aren't as descriptive as I'd like them to be. I am trying to edit some motor control functions, and in the GUI I am able to reach the form that contains buttons controlling the motor, but I'm not sure where the code is that controls this form. Is there a way to open up the code block corresponding to the form I navigate to from the GUI in debug mode?

Or, alternatively, how can I navigate through the GUI without running it? I know I can right click and do "View Code", so if I could navigate to the form I'd be able to that.

I am using VB.NET in Visual Studio 2010

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31346496/find-out-which-line-will-be-executed-in-visual-studio-debug-mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go by button text. In visual studio search(Ctrl+F) using the text, visual studio will find the designer.vb file holding the button with the text, once it is done try to look at the design of particular then you can figure out which form you need to look at.

thanks