# Breaking on code triggered by target application UI event in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I've been debugging a WPF application bequeathed to me by a gentleman who is fond of making interesting architectural decisions. As a result, I'm having trouble locating the code that runs when a user clicks an on-screen menu item. Following the binding from the view to the viewmodel got me to some collection of "control functions" that's initialized at startup (apparently, all manner of different controls with varying functions had to go into a single collection). I've managed to find some code that's triggered by the click, but it's too deep, too far removed from the click event to be of any use to me.

This got me thinking...

In Visual Studio, (I'm using VS2015) when the application isn't running, if you select Debug -> Step into, debug is triggered, and then the debugger breaks on the very first line of the code (in my case the constructor call of the class that inherits from System.Windows.Application)

Isn't there a way to do this while the application is already running? Let's say I've started a WPF (or WinForms) application, a window has been displayed, the UI thread is running and awaiting user input. The user clicks on a button, and some code is executed. But unless there's a breakpoint in the code, the debugger doesn't do anything about it. As I've explained, this can be a problem if I don't know which code is actually run. Is there a way to tell Visual Studio, "listen, if the user clicks on something, break on the first line of (user) code triggered by this action." Is that possible?

Comment: Have you ever tried fooling around with snoop? Has some good utilities for tracking down info like that.

Comment: Is it feasible to add a dummy IValueConverter to the button bindings? That way if it's bound to a RelayCommand (say) then you can put a breakpoint in the converter and examine the ActionTarget and MethodName of the execute handler.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31346496/find-out-which-line-will-be-executed-in-visual-studio-debug-mode